# remove all dups and negative numbers from 3 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I recently had a technical job interview. the code challenge i was asked to solve was given 3 arrays of numbers. goal was to remove all dups and negative nums
i was able to remove dups but not duplicates, so far i have the following code. what am i missing?

```
let array1=[10, 200, 10, 200, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, -99, -6, 0, -859]
let array2 = [100, 200, 100, 200, 689, 689, 200, 400, 210, 200, -58, 200, -305, -6, 0, -859]
let array3 =[100, 200, 100, 200, 689, 689, 200, 400, 210, 400, -6, 200, -305, -6, 0, -859]

const arrays = {
    array1,array2,array3
}


let nodups=Array.from(new Set(array1.concat(array2,array3)))
console.log(nodups);
```

Comment: "i was able to remove dups but not duplicates" What?

Comment: Seems like a phrase with a duplicate.

Comment: This makes no sense what is the difference between dups and duplications

Comment: Was it asked that the solution must be one array? "Removing duplicates from" sounds more like you need to keep three arrays.

Answer (score 1):

After getting a duplicate free array, you need to filter the array for only positive values.

```js
var array1 = [10, 200, 10, 200, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, -99, -6, 0, -859],
    array2 = [100, 200, 100, 200, 689, 689, 200, 400, 210, 200, -58, 200, -305, -6, 0, -859],
    array3 = [100, 200, 100, 200, 689, 689, 200, 400, 210, 400, -6, 200, -305, -6, 0, -859],
    result = Array
        .from(new Set(array1.concat(array2, array3)))
        .filter(v =>  v >= 0);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this is a perfect answer, so simple with ecma 6, i was not able to solve the question, so the interviewer showed me his answer which was about 40 lines of ecma5 code that was completely unreadable

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a Set and apply a filter

```js
let array1=[10, 200, 10, 200, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, -99, -6, 0, -859]
let array2 = [100, 200, 100, 200, 689, 689, 200, 400, 210, 200, -58, 200, -305, -6, 0, -859]
let array3 =[100, 200, 100, 200, 689, 689, 200, 400, 210, 400, -6, 200, -305, -6, 0, -859]

let res = [...new Set([...array1, ...array2, ...array3])].filter(e => e >= 0);
console.log(res);
```